# Why is vim syncronous in file loading and saving?

Tags: vim, sshfs

I'm working on vim over an sshfs mounted filesystem with very high latency. Opening and saving a file takes about 9 seconds of blocking the editor.

Is there a way that I can only block the tab I'm in and still work with other tabs while files are saving and loading?

Comment: You can copy it to your local filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Writing is a blocking operation because Vim is single threaded: you can't do two things at the same time.

AFAIK when Vim has written the file locally, SSHFS uploads it to the remote server before "notifying" Vim that it's done. The whole process can and does obviously take quite some time.

There are better ways: a VCS (Git, SVN, Mercurial…) or an FTP client with folder monitoring capabilities (Transmit, Yummy FTP, Fetch…) for example.